# How to change table column headers using an Observe Event or other reactive function in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

The below MWE code works fine, except that I'd like to change the output table column headers to sequentially ordered descriptors when the user clicks the "Modify" action button as shown in the image at the bottom.

In deriving the output for the image, I ran the below MWE code, clicked on the "Modify" action button, and into the modal dialog box that popped up I inserted additional columns of 2's and 3's into the input matrix at the top. In that little `table1` that is rendered at the bottom of the modal box shown below (basically a mirror of the matrix input box at the top of the modal box), I'd like the column headers to automatically and sequentially generate as shown in the image. I'd like to start with this `table1` rendered in modal dialog and once the column header labeling technique is figured out, I'll add it to the other tables rendered in the App.

Basically, I just want the "V"'s to be replaced with "Series " in the output tables.

I also checked the specifications for `renderTable` hoping there's a key for changing the V's to something else, but I found nothing.

I mistakenly thought this would be easy to do using `observeEvent` and reactivity, but I can't get it to work. After all, when run I the below simple lines of code in R studio console (no Shiny), it changes the table output headers just fine --- but I don't know how to incorporate this into Shiny reactively:

```
> default_mat <- matrix(c(1,24,0,1),4,1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL))
> colnames(default_mat) <- paste0("Series ", 1:ncol(default_mat))
> default_mat
```

Here´s the MWE code that I've tried pulling the above (conceptually) into:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

default_mat <- matrix(c(1,24,0,1),4,1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),paste0("Series ", 1:1)))

colnames(default_mat) <- paste0("Series ", 1:ncol(default_mat))

matrix3Input <- function(x, default_mat){
  matrixInput(x, 
              label = 'Series terms:',
              value = default_mat, 
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,names = TRUE), 
              cols = list(extend = TRUE,names = TRUE,editableNames = TRUE,delete = TRUE),
              class = "numeric") # close matrix input
  
  } # close function

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Inputs"),
  fluidRow(actionButton("modify","Modify"),
           actionButton("show","Show"),
           actionButton("hide","Hide"),
           actionButton("reset","Reset"),
           tableOutput("table2")
  ) # close fluid row
) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(mat = matrix3Input("matrix", default_mat), 
                       input = default_mat,
                       colHeader = colnames(input)
        ) # close reactive values
  
  hide("table2")
  
  observeEvent(input$modify,{
    showModal(modalDialog(
      rv$mat,
      tableOutput("table1"))
    ) # close show modal and modal dialog
    hide("table2")
  }) # close observe event
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    rv$mat <- matrix3Input("matrix", input$matrix)
    rv$input <- input$matrix
    input$matrix
  }, rownames = TRUE, colnames = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$show,{show("table2")})
  
  observeEvent(input$hide, hide("table2"))
  
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    hide("table2")
    rv$input <- default_mat
    rv$mat <- matrix3Input("matrix", default_mat)
  }) # close observe event
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    rv$input
  }, rownames = TRUE)
  
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
output$table1 <- renderTable({
    rv$mat <- matrix3Input("matrix", input$matrix)
    # rv$input <- input$matrix
    # input$matrix
    df1 <- input$matrix
    n <- dim(df1)[2]
    colnames(df1) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
    rv$input <- df1
    df1
  }, rownames = TRUE, colnames = TRUE)
```

[image: output]